# How do I reference my powershell scripts in my electron application after building and packaging?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have made a Electron Application, mainly for my helpdesk colleagues at work.

**What it does (Context):**

It provides a simple gui with different "Tasks" it can do. Example:

[image]

For this I'm using a combination of:

- Node with Electron
- React
- Node-Powershell

  ---

**The Problem:**

The app when I run it in Development Mode is running as it should. But after I build and package it with electron, the NPM package `node-powershell` can't find the `.ps1` scripts anymore. 
I think I already identified the problem, but I don't know what the solution to this problem is. 
`node-powershell` needs a path to a script and an array of commands. 
I have set it up like this:

```
    const p1 = require('path').resolve();
    const scriptPath = require('path').join(p1, 'src/PowershellScripts/AddMailboxPermissions.ps1');
```

And then `ps.addCommand(scriptPath, commands);` (node-powershell)

As said before this works fine in development mode with a webpack server, but when run after packaging I get this error:

> C:\Users\Huberdo\Projekte\Powershell-SAS-App\Client\builds\basic-electron-react-boilerplate-win32-x64\src\PowershellScripts\GetRemoteMac.ps1 cannot be found.

The reason is because the packaging has following structure. The `.ps1` files now have following path:

> C:\Users\Huberdo\Projekte\Powershell-SAS-App\Client\builds\basic-electron-react-boilerplate-win32-x64\resources\app\src\PowershellScripts

*So this is the main issue. How do I package this "the right way" so that it's actually working afterwards.*

**Infos:**

- I run this on a windows 10 x64 machine
- package.json scripts:

  - `"dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.build.config.js",
    "package": "webpack --config webpack.build.config.js",`
- When I run it in dev mode it resolves the correct path and everything is working just fine

I hope someone of you can help me or guide me into the right direction.

**Possible Idea:**

Reference a completely other path and copy the ps1 files into another directory with a gulp task? Never used it. Could this be a possible solution? If yes how to best approach this?

**Update**
When I copy the `src` folder from `C:\Users\Huberdo\Projekte\Powershell-SAS-App\Client\builds\basic-electron-react-boilerplate-win32-x64\resources\app` into the root `C:\Users\Huberdo\Projekte\Powershell-SAS-App\Client\builds\basic-electron-react-boilerplate-win32-x64` it's working again. So it's mainly a path issue and I don't know how to solve it.

Last but not least a direct link to the project on github:

https://github.com/dhuber666/Powershell-SAS-Tool

Here I call the `ps1` script:

https://github.com/dhuber666/Powershell-SAS-Tool/blob/SendAs/src/components/scriptsComponents/AddMailboxPermissions.js

**!Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, but the approach I am using for the PowerShell scripts is to create them as PowerShell modules. Then you can just place them in one of the valid PSModule location and you should be good to go. And you could just write a powershell script to copy you modules to the correct location and copy the package to the desktop or where ever it needs to be.

A very simple module could be something like this:

In **C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules** create a folder called **MyModuleTest**. In this folder create a file called **MyModuleTest.psm1**. In this PSM1 file create a function e.g.

```
function Invoke-MyModuleTest {

Write-host "This is My Module"

}
```

Save the file, open a powershell console session and then if you run Invoke-MyModuleTest it will output to the console.

You can read more about modules [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can also find some nice examples of more complex modules [here](https://github.com/arcanecode/PowerShell/tree/master/Pester)

Once your have converted your script to modules you can just call them like any cmdlet, I currently don't have anything I can share.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds interesting. Could please further explain how you are doing this? Do you have an example or something like that on github? Thx

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke update the original response, hopefully it is more useful